# Sql Plus how to copy a table with timestamp

Tags: sqlplus

I am trying to copy a data from a remote database in SqlPlus.
I have a source table like so

```
table_name: source_table

seqId  |   createDate 

1   | 10-SEP-02 02.10.10.123000 AM

2   | 10-SEP-01 02.10.10.123000 AM
```

with the seqId being a number and createDate being a timestamp.

I attempted to copy the data to my table with:

```
COPY FROM &user_name/&password@&database
REPLACE x_source_table USING
SELECT * 
FROM source_table;
```

but it throws an invalid data error.

I then attempted to cast the createDate in the syntax with

```
COPY FROM &user_name/&password@&database
REPLACE x_source_table USING
SELECT cast(createDate as Date) as createDate
FROM source_table;
```

to attempt to only copy the createDate but it did not work either.

Comment: You need to list the exact errors instead of saying "I wasn't able to". We need specifics in order to help. What makes you think the createDate column is causing an issue? Oh `COPY` does not support a TIMESTAMP datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the TIMESTAMP datatype is not supported by the `COPY` command you can't use `COPY`.  I found this: "The COPY command is not being enhanced to handle datatypes or features introduced with, or after Oracle8. The COPY command is likely to be made obsolete in a future release. ".  Here's some documentation for 10g: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/apb.htm.

You will have to look for an alternative method. Can you do this or a variation instead:

```
truncate x_dest_table;
insert into x_dest_table select <column_list> from x_source_table
-- or from x_source_table@dblink if you have a database link;
commit;
```

Or maybe use export/import?  Or get a csv of the source table and use sqlldr to load it?

At least you have some options.  Let us know what you end up doing.

Comment: Thanks but I had to use a copy command for sql because I had to do it with the sqlplus but if that isn't possible then I can only give up on this approach.
The closest will be to just copy the table with select statement minus the timestamp column then.